# Segmented controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uiscrollview, instagram

UIView,SegmentedController & UIContainerView in a ScrollView or something similar?

In my storyboard I have a VC containing a UIView at the top, segmented controller in the middle & 2 ContainerViewControllers at the bottom with  embeded segue's to new VC's.

In the new VC's I have a TableView & a CollectionView (For example, the Instagram profile).

My issue is that I need the SegmentedController and UIView to scroll with the ContainerView(TableView/CollectionView), at the moment only the ContainerView part scrolls and the parts above that are fixed.

Now I'm guessing I probably need to put everything into a UIScrollView, so I tried that & placed all the costraints correctly. But when It came to configuring it in the Swift file, I only really now how to set the height of the scroll but oviously the height I need can vary and isn't a fixed height!

If anyone can help me here that would be fantastic, or maybe point me towards a similar question already asked here? I have already looked, but did not find anything unfortunately!

Here's an image below explaining basically what I'm after, if above I wasn't very clear..

here is an example you can see: https://github.com/Jackksun/ScrollIssue

the image is here, as I dont have enough reputation I cannot place it in the post!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only UITableViewController. You will define three custom cells and in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** ask for the Index number, if it is 0 you will set the elements in that cell accordingly

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: TableViewCell!
    // stuff in UIView
    if indexPath.row == 0 { set the cell here}
    // for UISegmentedController
    if indexPath.row == 1 { set the cell here}
    // cells that will repeat
    if indexPath.row >= 2 { set the cell here}
    return cell
}
```

**Update1**
Define how many custom cells you will use in Attribute inspector for tableView, you will see them instantly in Storyboard

[image]

**Update 3**

Did you mean this? It is completely table view with 4 custom cells. I didnt use Collection view at all but I think it works as you wanted

[image]

Comment: Hi, interesting way...How would I set three custom cells with index numbers?

Comment: See my updated answer, tableView have automatic numbering of cells, the first one (the one on top) is always NSIndexPath.row = 0

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I didn't realise it was automaticatly NSIndexPath.row = 0! I'll give it a go shortly. Thanks

Comment: Hmm don't think this is working.. I can get the tableview(with tableViewCells to scroll correctly) but with the collection view, only that scrolls and all the other view remains still...! I can't believe no one has tried to recreate this segmented controller with tableview and collection view!! I cant find anything to do with over the web , apart from my questions!

Comment: I have tried so many things in the last month of researching it! if you can recreate the same as instagram profile with that sgemented controller, displaying collectionView then a tableView I'll buy it off you!

Comment: see the Update 2 of the answer if it is what you were looking for... I created it like I told you...

Comment: I mean this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yYxKa.jpg ; http://i.stack.imgur.com/IS2mS.jpg ; http://i.stack.imgur.com/mOidY.jpg ; http://i.stack.imgur.com/lh85v.jpg    As you'll see from the photos, there is a collectionView and tableView and a segmentedcontroller in the centre controlling them. Which scrolls with the entire view. If you download my project example thats linked in my question you'll see my issue at the moment is that the TVC & CVC scroll but the segmented controller doesn't!

Comment: how is the triple tableView done? 3 images in 1 cell?

Comment: Hmm, but how would I add the images from the server to the 3 images? I don't know how many images I will be downloading

Comment: if the number you downloaded is not easily divided by three you can create a white blank image and fill it with that, or you can hide the ImageView... or you can pay someone to code the whole thing for you :-)

Comment: I don't think I would be able to link 3 images to 1 tableview and then repeat that...I understand using a collectionView you just have 1 cell and then that multiplys by the amount in the server

Comment: this is in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**
`cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("threeImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
                for imageView in cell.tripleImages {
                    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img.png")
                }` triple images are outlet collection [UIImageView]

Comment: I'll give ago maybe later or tomorrow, or if you'd like to setup something with parse...If I can get it to work, I'll pay you something ;)

Comment: what do you wanna create?

Comment: This that we have been talking about but with images coming in from parse, too see if it works

Comment: it will work!, youcan contact me here mazeltov@sharklasers.com

Comment: hey Mazel, I tried it...But it displays the same image 3 times for each row!

Comment: then you did something wrong. I dont what else you expect I say to you when you dont share any code :-D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684679/ordering-images-downloaded-from-parse did that for you ;)